# Using arrays and do loops to condition statement in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

My data look like this:

```
id  q1  q2  q3  q4  pq1 pq2 pq3 pq4
1   1   2   1   1   1   2   1   1
2   2   3   3   2   2   2   1   1
3   1   2   3   3   2   1   3   3
4   3   1   2   2   3   2   1   1
5   2   1   2   2   1   2   3   3
6   3   1   1   2   2   1   3   3
```

q1 is a pre-test answer and pq1 is the post-test answer and is the same question as q1. So the same individual has two measures for each of the four questions. 
I am trying to write more efficient code to see if any of the answers changed from pre- to post. I am trying to use arrays and do loops to create a new variable called "nochange" that is an indicator of whether an individual's answers stayed the same across all 4 questions from pre- to post.

```
data example2;
set example;
if q1=pq1 and q2=pq2 and q3=pq3 and q4=pq4 then nochange=1;
else nochange=0;
run;
```

The above data step does what I want it to do. Is there a way to use an array statement and do loops in case I have a lot more than 4 questions in the survey and I want to avoid having to type it all out like above?

I tried something like this:

```
data example2;
set example;
array apre [4] q1 q2 q3 q4;
array apost [4] pq1 pq2 pq3 pq4;
do i=1 to 4;
if apre[i] = apost[i] then nochange=1;
else nochange=0;
end;
run;
```

But it did not perform the function correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly had it; the only problem is that you continue to write over `nochange` after a change has been identified.

If you want to just make a simple alteration to your code, you can use the [`min()` function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245915.htm) to make sure you don't overwrite a `0` in `nochange`:

```
if apre[i] = apost[i] then nochange = min(nochange, 1);
else nochange = 0;
```

---

An alternative is to stop your loop once a change is found. The following code does that, and introduces a few features that you may find useful:

```
data example2;
    set example;
    /* Use variable lists to define the arrays */
    array q{*} q:;
    array pq{*} pq:;
    /* Initialise your flag */
    nochange = 1;
    /* Use the dimension of one of the arrays the maximum */
    /* Specify the loop stops if a change is found */
    do i = 1 to dim(q) while(nochange = 1);
        /* Check for changes */
        if q[i] ~= pq[i] then nochange = 0;
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

Features:

- `*` as the array subscript: This asks SAS to determine the array length from the the array elements it is passed.
- [Variable lists](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000695105.htm) (`p:`, `pq:`): This is one of several ways to abbreviate several names in SAS. See sushils' answer for another example.
- [The `dim(array)` function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000213236.htm): This returns the number of elements in an array and is useful when you have used `*` in the array definition.
- [The `while(condition)` expression](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201276.htm): You can add a `while()` (or `until()`) expression to you `do ... to ... <by ...>` statement to add an additional condition that can stop the loop. The `while` condition is evaluated at the beginning of each iteration and the statements are only executed if the condition is true (whereas the `until` condition is evaluated at the end of each iteration and the loop only continues if the condition is false).

Alternatively, you can explicitly end the `do` loop by using the [`leave` statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202782.htm):

```
do i = 1 to dim(q);
    /* Check for changes */
    if q[i] ~= pq[i] then do;
        nochange = 0;
        /* Stop the loop */
        leave;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! All three solutions worked perfectly. My question variable names aren't actually the same as the one I provided in my question (I used them for clarity) so I had to change my variable question names to use the variable lists and array subscripts but it worked after I changed the names. This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if the below solution helps. Also, go through [**SAS Variable Lists**](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000695105.htm) if you prefer this solution.

```
data question;
  infile datalines missover dsd dlm=',';
  input id  q1  q2  q3  q4  pq1 pq2 pq3 pq4;
datalines4;
1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1
2,2,3,3,2,2,2,1,1
3,1,2,3,3,2,1,3,3
4,3,1,2,2,3,2,1,1
5,2,1,2,2,1,2,3,3
6,3,1,1,2,2,1,3,3
;;;;
run;

data solution;
  set question;
   array preTest(*) q1-q4;
   array postTest(*) pq1-pq4;
   array noChange(*) 8  noChange1-noChange4;

 do i=1 to dim(preTest);
   if preTest[i] = postTest[i] then noChange[i]=1;
   else noChange[i]=0;
 end;

 drop i;
run;
options ps=max ls=max nocenter;
proc print data=solution;run;
```

Comment: I am trying to create one new indicator variable called nochange. I actually tried something similar to what you did but it did not give me what I wanted. Thanks for the attempt, I really appreciate it!